# I can't figure out why this RewriteCond isn't working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm having trouble figuring out why my RewriteRules won't trigger. These rules are in an `.htaccess` file at the root directory of a subdomain of my website. I've turned on detailed logging for mod_rewrite in the VirtualHost but that isn't really helping me solve what's wrong, though the first three rules seem to be working simply by coincidence since their files exist at the requested location.

The goal of this set of rules is:
`sub.domain.tld/` -> passthrough/serve actual file
`sub.domain.tld/?q=test` -> passthrough/serve actual file with query args intact
`sub.domain.tld/.well-known/*` -> passthrough/serve actual file (for letsencrypt)
`sub.doamin.tld/*` -> `process.php?project=*`
`sub.domain.tld/*?q=test` -> `process.php?project=*&q=test` while handling unlimited number of query args

And the current `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
#serve actual file if viewing main page or doing https renewal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\?.+|\/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\.well-known.*
RewriteRule (.*) - [L,QSA]
#redirect everything else to the processing script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\w+)
RewriteRule \/(\w+) process.php?project=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need the leading slash in any rule so start by removing `\/` and see how you go from there. Also, you don't need quotes around conditions.

Comment: @Capsule no change.

Comment: Please post your new rules when you updated all of them, including the quotes I also mentioned a bit later

Comment: That being said, is that correct to assume you want to rewrite everything (including the query string) to `process.php?project=....` except if the file or folder requested exists on the server?

Comment: @Capsule All done, and yes even if the file exists barring index and .well-known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, This was actually a complex one and because most of the time, `%{REQUEST_URI}` tests are done using the `RewriteRule` itself, I got a bit confused and I'm sorry about that.

It turns out:

- %{REQUEST_URI} contains the leading slash
- the matching part of the `RewriteRule` doesn't

Also, keep in mind `%{REQUEST_URI}` doesn't contain the query string, as stated in the Apache manual:

> **REQUEST_URI**
>   The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

So, a rule like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\?.+` is pretty much useless as you'll never have a question mark in `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Also, and this probably is the most confusing part, when requesting `/`, `%{REQUEST_URI}` will contain the actual index file that has been served. So, if your `DirectoryIndex` is set to `index.php index.html` (in that order) and you have an `index.html` file in the root folder, `{REQUEST_URI}` will be `index.html`. If you have an `index.php` file, it will be `index.php`, but never `/`.

That being said, we can simply your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(\.well-known|index\.php$)
RewriteRule (.+)    process.php?project=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

Note that I added the `$` inside the brackets to only match the end of string character after `index\.php` but not after `\.well-known`, so anything after `\.well-known` will also match.

You will need to replace `index\.php` with `index\.html` if you have an html index.

Finally, you don't need 2 rules for that. It's always better to have only one and exclude some URLs from it.

*PS: you'll also notice you don't need to escape `/` as this is not considered as a regexp delimiter.*

Answer (score 0):

You just need this single rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skip files, directories and anything inside .well-known/ directory
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.|process\.php|\.well-known)(.+)$ process.php?project=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: It won't work as is, as existing files should be rewritten too (except the index and anything within `/.well-known/`)